# area of a triangle formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have to prove the following formula for area of triangle:

$[ABC]=r^2\cot(A/2)\cot(B/2)\cot(C/2)$

The problem is that in the problem it is not specified what $r$ is at all,so i've assumed it's the inradius,and that's what i've done:

$$[ABC]=2R^2\sin A\sin B\sin C=r^2\cot\frac{A}{2}\cot\frac{B}{2}\cot\frac{C}
{2}$$ where $R$ is the circumradius,then:

$$16R^2\sin \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2} \cos \frac{C}{2}=r^2 \cot\frac{A}{2} \cot \frac{B}{2} \cot \frac{C}{2}$$

$$16R^2 \sin^2\frac{A}{2} \sin^2 \frac{B}{2} \sin^2 \frac {C}{2} =r^2$$

-->now i apply $\sin^2 A/2=(s-b)(s-c)/bc$ respectively for $A,B,C$

$$16R^2 \frac{(s-b)^2(s-c)^2(s-a)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}=r^2$$

Finally by applying $abc=4R[ABC]$ and rearranging terms in the equation  i get :

$$[ABC]=\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{r}$$

which is clearly wrong...please help

Comment: Use $r=4R\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2$

Comment: ohhh i see , so actually the last equation is correct ... ,thanks @lab bhattacharjee ...btw your comment should be an answer +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a proof "geographically".[image]

One has $$\cot \frac{A}{2} = \frac{AG}{DG} = \frac{p-a}{r} = \frac{r(p-a)}{r^2} = \frac{S_{AEDG}}{r^2}$$

So, one has $$S_{ABC} = S_{AEDG} + S_{BEDF} + S_{CGDF} = r^2\sum \cot \frac{A}{2} = r^2\prod \cot \frac{A}{2}.$$

Comment: that's pretty neat ,thanks,